# Assigning unique selectors to unknown number of elements generated dynamically with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page which loads a table from PHP, with a variable number of lines depending on the results of a MySQL query.

The last cell of every row in the table contains a link. When the user clicks the link I want the data in *that row only* to be submitted to another PHP script via Jquery and Ajax.

The problem is that because the table is generated dynamically and the number of rows is variable, I don't know how to assign selectors to each row for the jQuery to grab hold of. Nor am I sure about how to get the values out of each table cell (although I have figured out a workaround to this using hidden inputs).

How do I assign selectors to both the clickable links themselves and the values that need submitting, bearing in mind there could be an infinite number of rows in the table.

For clarity, I've posted the PHP code that generates the table and an example of the table itself, but I'm looking for a jQuery solution.

Thanks!

**PHP**

```
while ($line = $run_check->fetch_assoc()){

    if ($i%2 != 0){
    $rowclass = 'reqodd';
        }
        else {
        $rowclass = 'reqeven';
        }
        echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $line['name'] . '" id="name' . $i . '" /><input type="hidden" value="' . $line['account'] . '" id="account' . $i . '"><input type="hidden" value="' . $line['module'] . '" id="module' . $i . '">;
        echo <tr class = "' . $rowclass . '"><td class="req">' . $line['name'] . '</td><td class="req">' . $line['account'] . '</td><td class="req">' . $line['module'] . '</td><td class="req"><a href="#" class="rel_link" id="rel_' . $i . '_link">Release</a></td></tr>';
        $i++;
          }
```

**Example Table** (The clickable links are in the 'release' column)

```
|   Name     | Level | Unit | Release |
|Joe Bloggs  |   4   | 401  | release |
|John Smith  |   6   | 611  | release |
|Jane Bloggs |   4   | 403  | release |
|Jane Smith  |   5   | 502  | release |
```

Comment: Would jquery closest work?     $("table a").click(function(){ $row = $(this).closest("tr"); });. $row would then hold all the data from that row which would be made into a query string and submitted to anythign via ajax?

Comment: or infact $row = $(this).parent("tr");

Comment: Is it possible to store the data as an array using this method? I need to send the data in each cell and insert it into separate MySQL fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting data from a database, then the table should already have an "ID" row. Just add it as a data attribute on the link, and use `this.getAttribute("data-id")` (for example) to get it when the link is clicked.

Comment: I don't know much about data attributes but am I right in thinking they are HTML5 only - as in, not going to work with all versions of IE? If that's the case then I need another solution, as an annoyingly large amount of my user base will probably use IE8, possibly even IE7!

Comment: Attributes have always been freely customisable. It's just that `data-*` attributes are specifically defined in HTML5 as not being used for any reason by the browser itself (in other words, no future version of HTML will ever use them)